# "crying to George Jones albums" what does "to" mean here?

Tags: expressions, prepositions

"Like me, Hugh was single, which came as no great surprise, considering that he spent his leisure time rolling out dough and crying to George Jones albums."

This is an excerpt from a book I have been reading lately. In the sentence above, the "to" in "crying to" has the same meaning as in "dancing to music"?

Also, I assume that the writer is trying to be funny when he says "crying". I do not think he literally cried. I think it is more like moaning. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do something *to* music, it means that you do it with music in the background. It often also implies that you do this thing according to the timing of the music. People normally:

- dance to music
- walk to music
- march to music
- tap their feet to music

Synchronised swimmers *swim to music*. Usually, it implies that the person is doing this thing deliberately, and that the music is there to help or invigour the activity.

The writer is using *cry to music* here to produce a special, amusing effect. Crying is normally an involuntary emotional reaction to something. But if you do "something to music" it normally implies that you put the music on to do this activity. So it faintly implies that Hugh puts the George Jones music on *so* that he can cry to it. It implies that his crying might be a bit affectatious - not genuine. It's also comic because it kind of  implies that maybe Hugh is crying *in time* with the music.

All of this is a bit pathetic and teenage-like, which is probably why Hugh is still single!

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand clearly! Your explanation fits with the context perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *crying to George Jones albums* means

> *crying [while listening] to George Jones albums*

Whether the phrase is supposed to be taken literally is a question of interpretation. The implication of the phrase is that the person is a romantic, emotionally moved by tales of love and love lost.